# Global folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows, directory, global

I want to allow all users to read and write in a file, through my application. The file is common to all users. Where should I put that file in Windows 7?

Comment: It depends. Do the users have a need to know of it's location?

Comment: If you're going to do this, please, please, remember that your code has to treat the file as potentially malicious, so that one compromised account can't infect others.  If you're not already familiar with it, a good start is the CWE/SANS top 25 most dangerous software errors: http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Known Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If users don't need to see the files the you can use:
**FOLDERID_ProgramData**  - default location will be "*c:\ProgramData*"

If the user needs to be able to browse and find the file then the "Public" user can be used.  Either **FOLDERID_Public** or **FOLDERID_PublicDocuments**.  That will default to "*c:\users\Public**"

You can check the [list of all the standard Known Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see if there is anything that would work better for you.  This page has the same list with [friendly descriptions on how they should be used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Use the function [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the path on the current system.  Don't assume the default values are valid.

If you need this to run on Windows XP then use the previous function [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  and equivalent CSIDLs.